# getting position of click and custom button inside a list using custom CursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

**Scenario**
Friends I have a ListView which I am using in a FrameLayout which will power my DrawerLayout for the sliding menu. I have custom buttons and text in my ListView which are defined as listitems in seperate xml. Now I am providing data to this ListView using a customAdapter which is extends CursorAdapter...

I want to get the position of the click and also the button click events to fetch data accordingly... my code below...

**List item XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    >


     <!--  ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        style="@style/toggleButton"
        android:background="@drawable/silent_button_selector"
        android:focusable="false"
         /> --> 

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_button"
        />


    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/calendarName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Adapter class:**

```
public class CalendarListAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements OnClickListener{

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public CalendarListAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.calendarName);
        System.out.println("cursor details"
                + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor
                        .getColumnName(1))));
        title.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor
                .getColumnName(1))));
        Log.d("click position " , "position is " +cursor.getPosition() );
        ImageButton button = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        Log.d("click position " , "position is " +cursor.getPosition() );
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View calendarListView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_list_item, null);

        return calendarListView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.d("item clicked", "clicked" );

    }

}
```

**What is happening now :**

with the above implementation, when I click button it give only button click events and when I click rows/list items I get the position alone.

**What I need to do?**

I need to get the position and the click event simultaneously so when I click button on 3rd row, i need position 3 and button clicked event...

Please let me know the best way to do this... Thanks for your time and efforts..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simple way to handle your scenario is to leverage the button tag

**in your bindView**

```
ImageButton button = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setTag(cursor.getPosition());
```

**and then in your onClick you can read the tag**

```
int position = (Integer) view.getTag();
```

Comment: Thanks let me try and will let you know.. But I have changed the ImageButtons to ToggleButtons now.. let me try doing this...@William Newby

Answer (score 0):

To user in Databases uses....

implement your Onclicklistener in your adapter..

in your bindview...

```
ImageButton button = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setTag(cursor.getint("number colunm _id here!!");
```

in your onclick...

```
int position = (Integer) view.getTag();
```

bye